# Relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol when calling function from inline assembly

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I am trying to build shared libraries that has some functions in assembly that call other functions. When I build `liba.so` with code

```
void aFunc1()
{
}

asm(
    ".globl aFunc2\n\t"
    ".type aFunc2, @function\n\t"
    "aFunc2:\n\t"
    ".cfi_startproc\n\t"
    "call aFunc1\n\t" /* note here*/
    "ret\n\t"
    ".cfi_endproc\n\t"
);
```

and command

```
gcc -o liba.so a.c -shared -fPIC
```

I got error

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccdGBiQv.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `aFunc1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It tells me to use option `-fPIC` but I just already use that option! However I find out that with option `-Wl,-Bsymbolic` it compiles fine.

```
gcc -o liba.so a.c -shared -fPIC -Wl,-Bsymbolic
```

Unfortunately problem comes back when I try build second library `libb.so` also with assembly functions that try call functions from first library. Compiling code

```
#include <a.h>

asm(
    ".globl bFunc2\n\t"
    ".type bFunc2, @function\n\t"
    "bFunc2:\n\t"
    ".cfi_startproc\n\t"
    "call aFunc1\n\t" /* note here*/
    "ret\n\t"
    ".cfi_endproc\n\t"
);
```

with command

```
gcc -o libb.so b.c liba.so -shared -fPIC -Wl,-Bsymbolic
```

gives error

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccaGvn5d.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `aFunc1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and as you can see option `-Wl,Bsymbolic` doesn't help.

I want to know how to build second library and why first library needs `-Wl,Bsymbolic` option. I am not assembly master so I don't know if it is correct — I'm trying to build someone else library. Maybe I should use other options?

Comment: `ld`'s "recompile with `-fPIC`" message is a suggestion that makes sense if the asm came from compiler output, instead of being hand-written.

Comment: Function calls across shared-object boundaries (from one library or exectuable to another library) need to use some kind of indirection: shared objects can be loaded more than 2GiB apart in virtual address space, so a `call rel32` can't always reach.  Also, ASLR and other factors mean the displacement can't be a link-time constant, and the linker is telling you that runtime fixups (editing of the machine code to adjust the displacement at dynamic link time) isn't available.  The 2GiB limit is *why* Linux dynamic linking isn't designed to allow that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call either the PLT stub because the function could have been interposed (making the call no longer direct, with a fixed offset):

```
call aFunc1@plt
```

With `-Bsymbolic`, the linker will turn this into a call to `aFunc1` (without the double indirection).

You can also call the function via the GOT, similar to what the PLT stub does:

```
jmp *aFunc1@GOTPCREL(%rip)
```

Or you can make the function hidden:

```
.hidden aFunc1
jmp aFunc1
```

Note that his will make the *definition* hidden as well, so the function is no longer exported.  To emulate the behavior of `-Bsymbolic` for a single symbol, you can use a hidden alias:

```
.set aFunc1Alias, aFunc1
.hidden aFunc1Alias
jmp aFunc1Alias
```

With the hidden function and the hidden alias, the call will always go to the same function, i.e., it is no longer possible to interpose the symbol for this particular call site.

Comment: Adding `@plt` to function calls works but I would like not to alter assembly code if it is possible. I noticed that library that I am trying to build is via nasty macros adding `__attribute__((visibility ("hidden")))` to `aFunc1` declaration in `libb.so` and adding nothing in `liba.so`. Is it possible to do it via that way? When I do that in my minimal example it still has relocation problems in `libb.so`.

Comment: `__attribute__((visibility ("hidden")))` causes GCC to emit a `.hidden` directive, so it is very similar. It may not be effective at the assembler level if it is only contained in a header file and the function is not called from C, though.